# Find out if a group $G$ of order $1000$ contains a proper normal subgroup $H$: Number of $p$-Sylow subgroups has many solutions

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

I want to find out if a group $G$ of order $1000$ contains a proper normal subgroup $H$.

1. Can one solve this without the use of Sylow theorems?
2. Let's assume we will use the theorems of Sylow. We write $1000=2^3 5^3.$ For $q=5$,we find that the number of $q$-Sylow subgroups, $n_q,$ has only the solution $n_q=1.$ That means that $G$ contains a normal sungroup $H$ of order $125.$ I have nevertheless a problem with $p=2.$ In that case I get $n_p\in \{ 1,5,25,125\},$ meaning that there are many solutions for $n_p$. What does this mean i.e. how many $p$-Sylow subgroups are there in $G$? Thanks for any comment.

Comment: If all you want is to show that $G$ is not simple, you are done, aren't you?

Comment: All values $n_2 = 1,5,25,125$ are possible for a group of $G$ of order $|G| = 1000$. That is, you can find a finite group of order $1000$ with exactly $125$ Sylow $2$-subgroups, another one with exactly $25$ Sylow $2$-subgroups, etc.

Comment: If you already know that there is a normal subgroup of order $125$, you know that $G$ is not simple and there is no need to consider anything about $2$-Sylows. That is if you only care about the question of whether $G$ is simple or not.

Comment: Thanks. As for the question about different values of $n_2,$ following your answer, only one of the $4$ possibilities for $n_2$ will hold given a group of order $1000,$ right? How do we know or is there any result showing which of these possibilities will hold for a given group of order $n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you find yourself, $G$ surjects onto a group of order 8 with kernel order 125. Both are prime-power order, therefore nilpotent and solvable, hence so is $G$.

As to the latter, let $D_{10}$ be the dihedral group of order 10　and $C_n$ be the cyclic group of order $n$. The former has five 2-Sylow subgroups, while the latter has one. It follows that $C_{1000}, C_{100}\times D_{10}, C_{10}\times D_{10}\times D_{10},D_{10}\times D_{10}\times D_{10}$ have 1,5,25,125 2-Sylows respectively.

Comment: Convention varies..., just rename as $D_5$, if you like.

Comment: Is the order of the dihedral group $D_n$ rather $2n$?

Comment: Ok.Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the following way. If $G$ is a group with subgroup $H$, put $core_G(H):=\bigcap_{g \in G}g^{-1}H g$. This is the largest normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $H$. Then use this, $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\gt 0}$.

**Proposition** Let $G$ be a group with a subgroup $H$ with $|G:H|=n$, then $G/core_G(H)$ embeds homomorphically into $S_n$.
**Proof** (sketch, this basically boils down to group theoretical bookkeeping; the proof can also be found on many places on this site) Let $G$ act by left multiplication on the left cosets of $H$. Then the kernel of this action is exactly $core_G(H)$. $\square$

Now, if $|G|=1000$, assume $G$ is simple and consider the Sylow $5$-subgroups of $G$: their number $n_5 \in \{1,2,4,8\}$. If $n_5=1$ then a Sylow $5$-subgroup is normal and you are done. The same holds for $n_5=2$, since then the normalizer $N_G(P)$ of $P \in Syl_5(G)$ has index $2$, and hence is normal. So we are left with the cases $n_5=4$, or $=8$. In the first case, by the proposition and the fact that $core_G(P)=1$ since $G$ was assumed to be simple, $G$ can be embedded in $S_4$, a contradiction, since $1000 \gt 24$. In the other case, $G$ embeds in $S_8$, but $125$ does not divide $8!$, again a contradiction, this time to Lagrange's Theorem.$\square$

**Note** A theorem of William Burnside says that a group of order $p^aq^b$, with $p,q$ primes and $a,b$ natural numbers must be solvable. His proof required character theory but later on a character-free proof was also found (Goldschmidt, Matsumaya and Bender).

Comment: Many thanks. In the case of $n_5$ only the solution $n_5=1$ satisfies the condition $n_5=1 \mod 5.$ I have only a problem with the case $n_2,$ since then many solutions for $n_2$ satisfy the required conditions by Sylow theorems.

Comment: Yes totally right. I understand your question now.